# What is this story? Very tall alien political exiles hiding on earth?

Tags: story-identification

The time - a year or more after Star Wars, certainly from the time when "Wow, Star Wars is big, what SF stories do we have?". I believe, but am not %100 certain on this that it had proudly emblazoned on the cover "From the publishers of Star Wars" (I may be conflating this with "Damnation Alley", which definitely did have this.

It was a fairly pulpy tale that involved political exiles from some alien planet being exiled to earth via some kind of stargate thingy (?) (earth of I guess the 60s or 70s).

They were human appearance, but I remember as being very tall?

There was possibly some back and forth stuff with the home planet, but I remember nothing else, except the cover was a character wielding something that was not exactly unlike a light-saber. Which was totally misleading, but the whole packaging screamed of "SF is big now, this is a SF book".

It's quite possible that it's by a well-known author, but I've not been able to remember anything else about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[***Star Giant,***](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31997) by **Dorothy Skinkle.** First published in paperback in 1969 (that's the edition I have), but reprinted in paperback in 1978 with a whole new cover design. Here's a scan of the front cover of that later edition. It doesn't mention any link to "Star Wars" in the bits of text on the cover -- but, as you described, there is a very lightsaberish look to what the guy is holding, even though I (like you) don't recall any scene within the book that included such a weapon.

[image]

The basic premise is also what you recalled (and accounts for my recognizing the book right away, since I had never seen the 1978 cover art before). For thousands of years, Earth has quietly been used as a penal colony -- a dumping ground for people who get in trouble with the government of Liban. Some of the exiles are simply sent to Earth for being younger sons of royalty, and thus potential threats to the current ruler of Liban. All Libans look just like us, except for tending to be a lot taller. (We're not talking two or three times as tall as an average man, but we do seem to be talking about something in the neighborhood of, say, seven feet tall.)

The exiles are sent here via some sort of teleportation technology, as you said -- not delivered via starships coming in for a landing in a quiet meadow in the middle of the night. Some of those giants ended up making names for themselves -- several are mentioned in Greek mythology, including Hercules, Atlas, and Antaeus. Goliath (from the Old Testament) was also an exile; as were some of the giants mentioned in Norse mythology, and so on and so forth.

A modern exile, Ben-oni, ends up meeting and falling in love with Janice Nordstrom, a six-foot-tall young lady who knows her grandfather was very tall and very mysterious, but was unaware that he too was an exile from another world. You called the plot "fairly pulpy," and I won't argue with that. It's a short novel, and not what I would call amazingly well-written or cerebral. I am not surprised that it hasn't been reprinted since 1978.

Comment: My god, you are correct .....  This is absolutely the book!  Maybe I had a british edition with the "star wars" link or I mis-remembered it, but this is definitely the cover artwork I remember.  You have just solved a 30 years mystery for me!!!!!

Comment: @Swordblaster Glad to help! Within the last few years I bought a used copy, very cheap, of the 1969 edition. Earlier today, someone posted a question for which the correct answer may have been Dickson's *Wolfling*, and I clicked on a link to another question with the same answer, which in turn led me to a link to right here. As soon as I read the title about "very tall alien political exiles," I had a strong suspicion, and the text of your post confirmed it. Although, as I said, mention of a "lightsaber" took me by surprise. But when I found that cover-scan, I knew I had to show it to you.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're referring to Wolfling by Gordy Dickson:

[image]

The aliens were very tall albinos who had contacted Earth to re-join their empire. They were clearly Homo Sapiens. Earth sent a rep to their empire to determine whether or not we were a colony of theirs lost in the mists of time, or if we were a case of parallel evolution, or if we were maybe the original cradle of humanity. The swords in question were controlled cones of plasma which could be extended or shortened at will. Which, as you might imagine, is considerably terrifying (think of a light saber able to spring out and reach you from across a large room).

Earth's rep, an Indiana Jones type of archaeologist/adventurer with the both of a 7 foot tall Arnold Schwarzenegger, determines that we were a colony because he himself is a genetic throwback. Despite how it sounds, the main character actually goes through the book by out-thinking folks around him. The combination of this body build and his intellect causes him to conclude that he is indeed a descendant of the albino ruling class of the Empire.

The ruling class, incidentally, is shown to be fairly unique in history. They are required to learn the entirely of the vast stores of science of their empire, and because they are not allowed to simply lay about eating peeled grapes all day. And this has meant a stable empire spanning thousands upon thousands of years. The albinism is done on purpose to mark the ruling class.

I haven't read the book for many years, but I remember enjoying it very much. No note about Star Wars on the cover, but those are clearly the lightsaber-style plasma swords which may have made you think of Star Wars. A different edition may mention Star Wars.